# In Symfony2 + Doctrine can mapping (orm) and validation YML files be combined?

Tags: validation, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

It's not vital by any means, but it would be nice to be able to combine the mapping definition (`.../Resources/config/doctrine/Foo.orm.yml`) and the validation rules (`.../Resources/config/validation.yml`) into one file (per class). In other words, I'm looking to add the validation rules to the mapping definition files.

Is there any way to do this or is it just going to confuse both YML parsers when they find keys that they don't expect in each class's YML file?

P.S. telling me to use annotations and put everything in one file that way is not an answer to the question!

Comment: Nope.  Can't be done unless you really want to dig into their respective yaml processors.

Comment: OK, thank you for confirming that for me!